How to replace columns value use replace?
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 2, 8, 9],
                   'C': [10, 2,2, 13, 14]})
#this work
#df_test['A'].replace({2:3},inplace=True) 

#this don't df_test still the same
df_test.loc[:,['A','B']].replace({2:3},inplace=True)

replace column 'A' and 'B'' but nothing changed

what are you replacing?

This is caused by pandas somewhat opaque view/copy on write (CoW) mechanism. When you take a slice of a dataframe (with, e.g. loc), then change some values in that slice, pandas may make a copy of that part of the dataframe, and apply the changes to the copy, leaving the original untouched. At other times it may return a 'view', and changes will affect the underlying dataframe. It is notoriously difficult to accurately predict which will happen.
For example, df_test.loc[:,:].replace({2:3},inplace=True) will work, changing the underlying dataframe. However,  df_test.loc[:,['A', 'B', 'C']].replace({2:3},inplace=True) won't, as pandas makes a copy of the dataframe, changes the copy in-place, then discards the new version (as it hasn't been assigned anywhere).
For this reason, I completely avoid inplace=True and use method chaining, e.g.:
df_test.loc[:, ['A','B']] = (
    df_test
    .loc[:,['A','B']]
    .replace({2:3})
)

This is getting a major review in Pandas v3. You can read about the current and future behaviour here.
